# jQuery: Background slideshow with text Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few questions:

1.) Is it better to use image or background change when using a slideshow, in what cases would you use one over the other?
2.) How do I get the **background to change to different images, along with the secondary text while keeping the big text the same?**  I feel like what I"m doing is probably not best practice...also I want it to loop continuously.

I'm just beginning to learn jquery and javascript and I know there's abunch of plugins for this but I'd like to learn as simply as possible how to achieve this.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/xv2vph6c/5/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.my-slide').addClass("slide-1");
setInterval(function () {
  $('.my-slide').addClass("slide-1");
     $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-2");
     $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-3");
}, 500);

    setInterval(function () {
  $('.my-slide').addClass("slide-2");
  $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-1");
     $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-3");
 
}, 1000);

        setInterval(function () {
  $('.my-slide').addClass("slide-3");
  $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-1");
     $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-2");
 
}, 1500);
  
});
```

```css
.my-slide{
  background:url('http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/07/19/candy-wallpapers_110702795_64.jpg') no-repeat;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
}
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}
.messages{
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-250px;
  margin-top:-50px;
}
h2{
  color:black;
  font-size:30px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
h3{
  color:red;
  font-size:20px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.other-content{
width:100%;
height:500px;
background:blue;
border:3px solid black;}
.slide-1{
 background:url('http://blog.hdwallsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/candy-wallpaper-5853-6020-hd-wallpapers.jpg');
}
.slide-2{
background:url('http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/07/19/candy-desktop-wallpaper_110659729_64.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-slide">
<div class="messages">
  <h2>
  This message doesn't change!
  </h2>
  <h3>
  This message Changes!
  </h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other-content">Other content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For learning purpose fine. But try avoid calling multiple intervals and the problem here is your not changing text as per slide changes. You have to pass some text to particular slide.

Please find the following updated fiddle:

```
<div class="my-slide">
       <div class="messages">
         <h3>
            dynamic text goes here
        </h3>
     </div>
   </div>
 <div class="other-content">Other content</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.my-slide').addClass("slide-1");
setInterval(function () {
  $('.my-slide').addClass("slide-1").find('.messages h3').text("text");
     $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-2");
     $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-3");
}, 500);

    setInterval(function () {
  $('.my-slide').addClass("slide-2").find('.messages h3').text("changing");;
  $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-1");
     $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-3");

}, 1000);

        setInterval(function () {
  $('.my-slide').addClass("slide-3").find('.messages h3').text("changed");;
  $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-1");
     $('.my-slide').removeClass("slide-2");

}, 1500);

});
```

`updated fiddle`[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/xv2vph6c/9/